# Playing Audio Upon Starting an Android App

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am creating a splash screen for an Android application. It should not be a delay, but rather serve the purpose of a loading screen. I already have the visual element of it working, but cannot think of how to implement the audio. Just to be clear I do not want to put the code in onCreate(); it needs to play as soon as the app is opened. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OnCreate of the first Activity to be launched is the earliest you can start the audio.  Its the right place to put it if you want it to play immediately.  Unless you want it to continue to play after the loading activity is finished-  in that case the onCreate should start a service which plays the music.

Comment: How then are apps like those made by Supercell able to play sound as soon as they are opened?

Comment: On create is called as soon as you're opened. I think you are either a bit confused or not communicating your problem clearly.

Comment: In the AVD, onCreate() has a significant delay for me. The visual element to my splash screen displays itself, essentially serving as a loading screen, and the audio plays after it has already disappeared.

Comment: THen you need to put the code in the onCreate that sets up your splash screen.  You have more than 1 activity here.  Your splash screen can't even show if its onCreate isn't called.

Comment: Okay I will try that. I did not have a explicit splash activity, rather I set the default background as the one I wanted for my splash screen and just changed it in my game activity. It seemed like the easiest way to do it at the time, but it also seems to be the root of all my issues. Thanks for the help!